# LibGDX: How does unprojecting world coordinates work?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm having issues on a conceptual level understanding this, as most articles/questions don't go in depth.

I understand that the camera focuses on a part of the game world, like a real camera would.

So world coordinates are the coordinates/measurements of the world, correct? and Screen coordinates are the coordinates of the screen (whether it's a phone or a Desktop Launcher), right? Do viewports handle both the world size/coordinates and also the intended screen size/coordinates?

Whenever I use the `unproject` method, whether by calling `viewport.unproject` or `camera.unproject` (with `Gdx.input.getX()` and `Gdx.input.getY()` as parameters for the `Vector3` argument for the `unproject` method), nothing else changes.

My intended game width and heigh are 136 and 204 (aspect ratio). I have methods such as "if x >32 ...." but obviously thsee create issues because when I run it on different devices (or even my desktop launcher), the coordinate at 32 is very different. How do I make it the same? Is this what unproject method  solves?

How is it supposed to work? Is it designed so that wherever I touch on the screen, the touch will be mapped to what ever is on the world where I touched?

Usually I will call this:

```
Gdx.app.log("x", Gdx.input.getX() + "");
Gdx.app.log("y", Gdx.input.getY() + "");
```

But when I call the `unproject` methods, the coordinates stay the same. Am I not interpreting it right?

Is it better to just use `box2d` actors instead? Or will I get the same issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use it like this:

```
Vector3 touch;

cam.unproject(touch.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
```

then `touch.x` and `touch.y` are your unprojected coordinates.

Comment: I have a gesture listener class. So would I call the method inside of the touchdown method of the class? Or can I call the method anywhere?

Comment: Nothing is changing for some reason. My app log is still recording the regular screen coordinates.

Comment: did you read the second part of the answer? touch.x and touch.y are your new touch coordinates

Comment: OMG thank you so much. I didn't know you had to pass touch.x and touch.y into the parameter. Either way thank you so much!!!!